# Log to Google Cloud logging but not to the console

Tags: winston, google-cloud-logging

We're using [@google-cloud/logging-winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston) to handle our logs. These logs are also being logged to the console of the pod. I would like to prevent the logs from showing in the console because it takes up memory. Is it possible to have the logs only show up in Google Cloud logging but not in the console?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your setup, but provided you've used the snippet from the linnked NPM page under 'using the client library', you can achieve this by removing the console transport (`new winston.transports.Console()`) passed into createLogger.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow thanks, I did this and it seems to work.

```
const consoleOptions = { handleExceptions: true }

const consoleTransport = new transports.Console(consoleOptions)

const loggerOptions = {
  level: logLevel,
  transports: appEnvironment === 'production' ? [] : [consoleTransport],
  exitOnError: false,
  format: loggerFormat,
  handleExceptions: true
}
```